# convergence of series: $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})\cdot(x+1)^n $

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I would like to prove the convergence of series: $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})\cdot(x+1)^n $$ for x $\in \mathbb{R}$. I am a bit lost on this one. I guess I would be interested in

- $x<-1$
- $x = -1$
- $x > -1$

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What tools do you have at your disposal?

Comment: Actually, you'll want to consider $|x+1|<r$, $|x+1|=r$ and $|x+1|>r$ for some "radius" $r$.

Comment: @charlestoncrabb the basic criterias, L' Hopitals

Comment: I would suggest the ratio test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\dfrac{\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}\dfrac{|x+1|^{n+1}}{|x+1|^n}\to|x+1|$. By the ratio test, the series conveges in $(-2,0)$ and diverges in $(-\infty,-2)\cup(0,\infty)$.

Now, $\sum_{k=1}^n(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k})=\sqrt{n+1}-1\to\infty$. Thus series diverges for $x=0$.

Can you solve for $x=-2$?

Comment: This $ \dfrac{\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}$ as n goes to $\infty$ goes to $\frac{1-1}{1-1}$ which is  $\frac{0}{0}$  no?

Comment: Both numerator and denominator tends to 0, but all the fraction tends to 1

Comment: I am probably forgeting some basic rule, but why to 1?

Comment: Mutlplying for $\dfrac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}\times\dfrac{\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n+1}}$ and then factor $\sqrt{n+1}$ give us the result

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** you want to use the [Root test](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjJnPmBj6XKAhXDLQ8KHROFDJUQFgggMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FRoot_test&usg=AFQjCNEYT9JI-kiJRk92sfwmGcS3fk9Y4A&sig2=xUDPpmND0A8YrBSuRQidNQ) so you want to calculate
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}\dfrac{|x+1|^{n+1}}{|x+1|^n} = |x+1|$$
and find the values for which the limit is $< 1$.
So the series converges
$$\forall x | |x+1| < 1\\
\forall -1 < x + 1 < 1\\
\forall -2 < x < 0$$